# How to perform a clean json for a carriage return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I've a problem on a clean json string on a textarea.

I've a form with a textarea. A validation, it sends an email by taking the forms of information.

But I get an error when I pass a line in my textarea.

Ma fonction JS :

```
function submit() {
  var path = $(location).attr('href');
        try {
        var parameters = '{  "url" : "' + escape(path) +                            
                        '", "prénom" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputFirstname").val()) + 
                        '", "nom" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputLastname").val()) +                           
                        '", "email" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputEmail").val()) + 
                        '", "message" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputMessage").val()) +                            
                        '", "captchachallenge" : "' + capchallenge + 
                        '", "captcharesponse" : "' + capresponse  + '" }';

        contentSubmit = $("#submitArea").html();
        $("#submitArea").empty().html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '_vti_bin/json/service.svc/submit',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: parameters,
            success: function (msg) {
                submitSucceeded(msg);
                $("#submitArea").empty().html(contentSubmit);
                 resetRealPersonCaptcha();
            },
            error: submitFailed
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Error invoking service' + e);
        clearUploadPart();
    }
    //Recaptcha.reload();
}
```

The function who clean values in json properties so as to send a valid json request :

```
function cleanJSONString(str) {
    if (typeof str == 'undefined' || str == null)
        return "";


    //clean values in json properties so as to send a valid json request    
    return str.replace(/[/\\""]/g, "")
              .replace(/\\n/g, "")                  
              .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
              .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
              .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
              .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
              .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");      
}
```

And my ASP form :

```
<div id="content_title">
                    <h1>Submit</h1>
                </div>
                    <div class="submit">
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="field"><input id="inputFirstname" type="text" value="First name *" class="watermark" name="firstname"/></div>
                            <div class="field"><input id="inputLastname" type="text" value="Last name *" class="watermark" name="lastname"/></div>
                            <div class="field"><input id="inputEmail" type="text" value="E-mail *" class="watermark" name="email"/></div> 

                        <div class="right">
                            **<div class="textarea"><textarea id="inputMessage" name="message" class="watermark">Add your message here</textarea></div>**

                                <img id="other_upload_process3" alt="" style="height:20px; display:none;" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
                                <img id="other_upload_success3" alt="" style="width:20px; height:20px; display:none;" src="/images/Check.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:left;width:100%; margin-top:30px;">
                            <div id="captchadiv"><input id="captchaInput" type="text" value="Enter validation text *" name="captchaInput" class="watermark" style="margin-top:10px;"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="submit_container" id="submitArea">
                            <a onclick="javascript:submit();" class="btn orange height_19 submit"><span>
                            SEND FORM</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I don't understand why i've an error when I pass a line in my textarea.
Do you have any idea ? 
Is this an error in json properties so as to send a valid json request ?

Comment: What is the error you get? Maybe it will be better to build an actual Javascript object instead of a string, and pass that in the `ajax.data` property? Then you may not even need to clean the values

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Use JSON.stringify and what is `.replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")` doing? Looks to be adding back the same thing. Did you mean to have `\\\\&` as the replacement?

Comment: I would like to replace the newline, should we not?

Comment: In fact, I do the same thing. I removed the line ".replace (/ \\ / g," \\ ")" but it changes nothing.
I have an error sending me "An error occurred" because of my job:
submitFailed function (error) {
alert ('An error occurred.');
resetRealPersonCaptcha ();
$ ("# submitArea") empty () html (contentSubmit)..;
}

If I put everything on one line, it works